# How to insert rows dynamically in html bootstrap table, with values from dropdownlist in .net 5.0?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

**1. Explaination:**

I am creating an invoice page.

To populate the row data I am using a dropdown (i don't know a better way).

Now, I can successfully insert the data on the row but, when I select the dropdown value on any row, it changes the value of all the rows, when it should have changed only the selected one.

**2. Question:**

What am I doing wrong?

How can this be solved?

**3. My frontend code:**

```
 <table id="table1" border="0">
                <tr style="font-size:80%;">
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th style="width:50%;">Product</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;">qty</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;">price</th>
                    <th class="d-print-none">X</th>
                    @* <th class="d-print-none"></th>*@
                </tr>
                @{
                    int i = 0; 
                            foreach (var item in Model.PL)
                    {
                        <tr class="border-bottom">
                            <td class="tbl_id">1</td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="Products" asp-for="@Model.PL[@i].ProdId" class="form-control" type="text" name="data[@i][ProdId]" onchange="copyProd(this)" style="width:100%;"    >
                                  
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.PL)
                                    {
                                        <option    value="@item.ProdId"    
                                                qty="@qty"
                                            price="@Convert.ToInt32(item.price)">@item.name,   @Convert.ToInt32(item.price)</option>
                                    }

                                </select>

    <script>
            function copyProd(el) {

                let op = el.options[el.selectedIndex];
                let myvalue = el.value;
                let qty = op.getAttribute('qty');
                let price = op.getAttribute('price');

                //document.getElementById('xqtyId').value = qty;
                //document.getElementById('xpriceId').value = price;
                $("input[name='qty[@i]']").val(qty);
$("input[name='price[@i]']").val(price);
            }
        </script>
                            </td>
```

@* *@
                            
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                
                   
                    
                    //JS class to price/delete rows in html table - https://coursesweb.net/javascript/
                    //receives table id
                    function adRowsTable(id) {
                        var table = document.getElementById(id);
                        var me = this;
                        if (document.getElementById(id)) {
                            var row1 = table.rows[1].outerHTML;

```
                        //prices index-id in cols with class .tbl_id
                        function setIds() {
                            var tbl_id = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id + ' .tbl_id');
                            for (var i = 0; i < tbl_id.length; i++) tbl_id[i].innerHTML = i + 1;
                        }

                        //price row after clicked row; receives clicked button in row
                        me.priceRow = function (btn) {
                            btn ? btn.parentNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', row1) : table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row1);
                            setIds();
                        }

                        //delete clicked row; receives clicked button in row
                        me.delRow = function (btn) {
                            btn.parentNode.parentNode.outerHTML = '';
                            setIds();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //create object of adRowsTable(), pass the table id
                var ob_adRows = new adRowsTable('table1');
            </script>
```

**4. The backend code:**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        try
        {
            PL = await _context.Products.ToListAsync();

            var addrows = new List<InvoiceRows>()
        {
            new Products() { ProdId = 1, qty = 1, price = 0 },
            new Products() { ProdId = 1, qty = 1, price = 0 },
            new Products() { ProdId = 1, qty = 1, price = 0 },
        };

            PL = addrows;

            ViewData["ProdId"] = new SelectList(_context.Products, "ProdId", "Name");
        }
        catch (Exception e) { _ = e.ToString(); }

        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InvoiceRows InvoiceRow { get; set; } = default!;
    public IList<Products> PL { get; set; } = default!;
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(List<InvoiceRows> addRow)
    {

        _context.InvoiceRows.AddRange(addRow);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Comment: I included the "html" and posted the OnGet and the OnPost, backend code. Hope this helps to clarify things out.

Comment: it's hard to understand your dropdown, <option> doesn't contain the defintion for qty or price

Comment: Is it your purpoes: pass an 2D array which contains all properties of your all prodcuts and the drop down read text & id property form the array ,when you select one , dispalay the info in other inputs and remove the info related from the array,when you delete the row, add the info back to the array

Comment: @RuikaiFeng, i updated the dropdownlist, it seemed when i iniserted the code some parts were not visible.

Comment: @RuikaiFeng, i updated the dropdownlist, it seemed when i inserted the code some parts were not visible. I want to pass the data from the dropdown to the <input>. Each row will have its own values, which can be edited on need. I can already remove/delete rows. My problem is with the dropdown that indipendently from the row i select to insert data, it inserts/edits the data of the first row only. I want the dropdown to fill/edit the inputs of only the row i have selected. For example: If i select row nr.3, the dropdown will insert or edit the values only on row nr.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

although you haven't shown the full table

it seems you tried with jquery selector incorrectly

```
$("input[name='qty[@i]']").val(qty);
$("input[name='price[@i]']").val(price);
```

You could try with parent/children to select the correct input instead of all the inputs

here's a minimal example may help you to modify the value of the input accord with the select in the same row:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Prop1</th>
        <th>Prop2</th>
        <th>Prop3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input value="P11"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value="P12"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select >
                 <option >default</option>
                <option value="1" qq="qq1">OP1</option>
                <option value="2" qq="QWE1">OP2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <input value="P21"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input  value="P22"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select >
                <option >default</option>
                <option value="1" qq="qq2">OP1</option>
                <option value="2" qq="QWE2">OP2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("select").change(function(){

        var selectValue = $(this).children('option:selected').attr("value");
        var qq=$(this).children('option:selected').attr("qq")
        $(this).parent().prev().children('input').val(selectValue)
        $(this).parent().prev().prev().children('input').val(qq)
       
       
    })
</script>
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

```
$("select").change(function().....
```

The function was bound to the html element(selectlist) when the page was rendered(the selectlist you added haven't bound to the function ),if you  want it work for a new row

try bind then function to `document`

```
$(document).on('change','select',function(){

        var selectValue = $(this).children('option:selected').attr("value");
        var qq=$(this).children('option:selected').attr("qq")
        $(this).parent().prev().children('input').val(selectValue)
        $(this).parent().prev().prev().children('input').val(qq)
    })
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Ruikai Feng, please define what a full table is. Maybe i did not understood your request, so i can add what you asked for. The code works great for static rows, but how do i have to edit it to work for dynamic rows?   I tried : $(this).parent().prev().children("input[name='qty[@i]']").val(qty)
$(this).parent().next().children("input[name='price[@i]']").val(price), but it edits only the first row. All the other rows remain blank/null.

Comment: the jquery codes would work for all select,firstly find the parent node(<td> ) of the current selectlist(which you selected an option ),then access the prev <td> node with .prev() and select the child node<input> with .children('input')

Comment: And what's your dynamic rows? like when you click a button ,it generate a new row contains the same input/dropdown?

Comment: I got it ,I'll deliever the solution to you tomorrow

Comment: Yes, on button click it adds a new row which contains the same input/dropdown. You can find the full code of inserting a new row, on page top.

Comment: I've updated my  answer,please check it