# How to save Invoice Header and invoice rows on single page submit form with .net core razor pages?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

**1.Explaination**

I want to open the "Create" page, fill the invoice header data, fill the invoice dynamic rows data and save everything on one single submit.

(* Updated code)
I managed to solve the RowList error, which did not let me add multiple rows:

[How to insert multiple rows with AddRange in ASP.NET Core Razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716824/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-with-addrange-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/75717334#75717334)

Now i am getting an error

**1.1 The error**

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

```
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
EPIDENT5.Pages.Magazina.Pages_Magazina_Create.<ExecuteAsync>b__28_0() in Create.cshtml
```

...

```
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.RowList.Count(); i++)
```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(bool useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
EPIDENT5.Pages.Magazina.Pages_Magazina_Create.ExecuteAsync() in Create.cshtml

```
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
```

**I know i am missing something but can not understand where the problem is.**

**2.Question**

How can this be done?

**3. The frontend code:**

```
<form method="post">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>


// This is the header table 



                <table class="table table-striped border-0"
                       style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
                    <thead class="border-0">

 <tr class="border-0">
                    <td class="border-0" style="min-width:100%;">
                        <div class="border border-secondary p-4">
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
                                    <div class="form-group m-1">
                                        <label asp-for="InvHeader.Cli" class="control-label" style="font-size:80%;">Client</label>
                                        <input asp-for="InvHeader.Cli" class="form-control" value="clients name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:left;width:25%;">
                                    <div class="form-group m-1">
                                        <input asp-for="InvHeader.InvDate" class="form-control" type="date" value="@(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="InvHeader.InvDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:left;width:25%;">
                                    <div class="form-group m-1">
                                        <input asp-for="InvHeader.InvNr" class="form-control" value="33" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="InvHeader.InvNr" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>



//This is the dynamic rows table



 <table id="table1" border="0">
            <tr style="font-size:80%;">                  
                <th style="width:50%;">Product</th>
                <th style="width:5%;">qty</th>
                <th style="width:5%;">price</th>
            </tr>
                        foreach (var item in Model.PL)
                {
                    <tr class="border-bottom">                           
                        <td>
                            <select id="Products" asp-for="@Model.PL[@i].ProdId" class="form-control" type="text" name="data[@i][ProdId]" style="width:100%;"    >
                              
                                @foreach (var item in Model.PL)
                                {
                                    <option    value="@item.ProdId"    
                                            qty="@qty"
                                        price="@Convert.ToInt32(item.price)">@item.name,   @Convert.ToInt32(item.price)</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].qty" class="form-control" type="text" name="qty[@i]" style="width:100%;" /></td>
                                <td><input asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].price" class="form-control" type="text" name="price[@i]" style="width:100%;" /></td>
                     </tr>
                     </table>
                     
                     </form>
```

**4.The backend code**

//The data binding part

```
 [BindProperty]
    public InvHeader InvHeader { get; set; } = default!;
    public IList<InvRow> RowList { get; set; }
```

//The onget method, where row count id red

```
 public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
    {

        var rr = new List<InvRow>()
        {
            new InvRow() { Name = "Apple", Qty = 5, Price = 100 },
             new InvRow() { Name = "Peach", Qty = 3, Price = 500 },
              new InvRow() { Name = "Ananas", Qty = 1, Price = 1100 },
        };

        RowList = rr;

        return Page();
    }
```

//The Onpost method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IList<InvRow> RowList)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

         _context.InvHeaders.Add(InvHeader);

        await _context.InvRows.AddRangeAsync(RowList);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Fillo, what's the `PL` property? How do you define it in the backend?

Comment: Hi @Rena, the PL is the product list. It seems that when i inserted the code it did not get visible. The asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].price" part and the dropdownlist are used because the rows are beeing added dynamically with some javascript, to save some time on page refreshing on each submit and of course for practicability. The dropdownlist (through some javascript) inserts the product values in the new dynamic row, that is why you see "qty" and "price" in the <option>.

Comment: Hi @Fillo, so which elements you want to post to the `addrows`? The product seems does not related to the `List<InvRows> addrows`. Pls share more details. And as my answer said, your `qty` and `price` attribute in the option make no sense for anything.

Comment: The addrows inserts dynamically the invoice rows. Here you can find, the full insert rows code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75635909/how-to-insert-rows-dynamically-in-html-bootstrap-table-with-values-from-dropdow

Comment: Hi @Fillo, so you mean you select the dropdownlist and then use js function to add the two elements with the selected qty and price value, right? If so, just refer to what I said in my answer, model binding binds the property by name attribute, so when you use js to add dynamic row, the element name should be:`addrows[index].propertyName` here in your scenario instead of `name="qty[index]"`.

Answer (score 1):

Model Binding binds the property by name attribute. The correct name attribute which matches the parameter should be like:`addrows[index].propertyName`.

Not sure what is your `PL` in your page, but it seems only `qty` and `price` input are related to the `InvRows` model. You need change the two inputs name like below:

```
<td><input asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].qty" class="form-control" type="text" name="addrows[@i].qty" style="width:100%;" /></td>
<td><input asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].price" class="form-control" type="text" name="addrows[@i].price" style="width:100%;" /></td>
```

If the select element is also related to the `InvRows` model, just change the select name like: `addrows[@i].ProdId`. Any way, the name depends on how is your model like.

Besides, your page contains duplicated foreach with same name, it is not correct. Assume that is should be:

```
@for(int i = 0;i<Model.PL.Count();i++)
{
        
<tr class="border-bottom">
    <td>
        <select id="Products" asp-for="@Model.PL[@i].ProdId" class="form-control" type="text" name="data[@i][ProdId]" style="width:100%;">

            @foreach (var item in Model.PL)
            {
                <option value="@item.ProdId">@item.name,   @Convert.ToInt32(item.price)</option>
            }
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].qty" class="form-control" type="text" name="addrows[@i].qty" style="width:100%;" /></td>
    <td><input asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].price" class="form-control" type="text" name="addrows[@i].price" style="width:100%;" /></td>
</tr>
}
```

A whole working demo you could follow:

Model

```
public class InvHeaders
{
    public int CliId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvDate { get; set; }
    public string InvNr { get; set; }
}
public class InvRows 
{
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public int ProdId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

Page

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <table class="table table-striped border-0"
           style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
        <thead class="border-0">
            <tr class="border-0">
                <td class="border-0" style="min-width:100%;">
                    <div class="border border-secondary p-4">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div style="float:left;width:25%;">
                                <div class="form-group m-1">
                                    <label asp-for="InvHeader.CliId" class="control-label" style="font-size:80%;">Client</label>
                                    <select asp-for="InvHeader.CliId" class="form-control font-weight-bold text-primary" asp-items="ViewBag.FurId"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="float:left;width:25%;">
                                <div class="form-group m-1">
                                    <input asp-for="InvHeader.InvDate" class="form-control" type="date" value="@(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="InvHeader.InvDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="float:left;width:25%;">
                                <div class="form-group m-1">
                                    <input asp-for="InvHeader.InvNr" class="form-control" value="" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="InvHeader.InvNr" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <table id="table1" border="0">
        <tr style="font-size:80%;">
            <th style="width:50%;">Product</th>
            <th style="width:5%;">qty</th>
            <th style="width:5%;">price</th>
        </tr>
       
        @for(int i = 0;i<Model.PL.Count();i++)
        {
            
        <tr class="border-bottom">
            <td>
                <select id="Products" asp-for="@Model.PL[@i].ProdId" class="form-control" type="text" name="data[@i][ProdId]" style="width:100%;">

                    @foreach (var item in Model.PL)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.ProdId">@item.name,   @Convert.ToInt32(item.price)</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].qty" class="form-control" type="text" name="addrows[@i].qty" style="width:100%;" /></td>
            <td><input asp-for="@Model.MR[@i].price" class="form-control" type="text" name="addrows[@i].price" style="width:100%;" /></td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="POST" />
</form>
```

PageModel

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public InvHeaders InvHeader { get; set; } = default!;
    [BindProperty]
    public InvRows InvRow { get; set; } = default!;
    public IList<InvRows> MR { get; set; } = default!;
    public List<Product> PL { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {   
        //hard-coded the value is just for easy testing
        PL = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product(){ProdId=1,name="aa",price=12},
            new Product(){ProdId=2,name="bb",price=16},
            new Product(){ProdId=3,name="cc",price=21}
        };
    }
    public void OnPost(List<InvRows> addrows)
    {
         //do your stuff....
    }
}
```

---

Just a note, there is no `qty` or `price` attribute in default `option` element below, not sure what do you want to do but I need remind you that it makes no sense for model binding.

```
<option value="@item.ProdId" qty="@qty" price="@Convert.ToInt32(item. Price)">
```

Comment: I do not know why, but i am getting Null reference exception, on rows count. I am adding the rows dynamically, and i can not understand what is wrong. All the input values are filled with data.    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

EPIDENT5.Pages.Magazina.Pages_AddInvoice.<ExecuteAsync>b__49_8() in AddInvoice.cshtml, line 253

Comment: Hi @Fillo, this error caused by null value. You need check the line 253 in your `AddInvoice.cshtml` and the value you used in that line is null.

Comment: Hi @Rena, i updated the code (i simplified it), solved the add rows part, but i am still getting an error. Please see above for the full code.

Comment: Hi @Fillo, for the error, you need check if the `RowList` contains value in OnGet method in Create.cshtml.cs  filr.

Answer (score 0):

**This what worked for me:**

**1. This is the frontend code**

```
 <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

       
        <table class="table table-striped border-0"
               style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
            <thead class="border-0">
                <tr class="border-0">
                    <td class="border-0" style="min-width:100%;">
                        <div class="border border-secondary p-4">
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
                                    <div class="form-group m-1">
                                        <label asp-for="InvHeader.Cli" class="control-label" style="font-size:80%;">Client</label>
                                        <input asp-for="InvHeader.Cli" class="form-control" value="clients name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:left;width:25%;">
                                    <div class="form-group m-1">
                                        <label asp-for="InvHeader.Cli" class="control-label" style="font-size:80%;">Date</label>
                                        <input asp-for="InvHeader.InvDate" class="form-control" type="date" value="@(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="InvHeader.InvDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:left;width:25%;">
                                    <div class="form-group m-1">
                                        <label asp-for="InvHeader.Cli" class="control-label" style="font-size:80%;">Nr</label>
                                        <input asp-for="InvHeader.InvNr" class="form-control" value="33" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="InvHeader.InvNr" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

        <table id="table1" border="0">
            <tr style="font-size:80%;">
                <th style="width:50%;">Name</th>
                <th style="width:5%;">qty</th>
                <th style="width:5%;">price</th>
            </tr>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.RowList.Count(); i++)
            {

                <tr class="border-bottom">
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                              <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[@i].Name" class="form-control" name="RowList[@i].Name"  />
                            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[@i].Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[@i].Qty" class="form-control" name="RowList[@i].Qty" value="1" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[@i].Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[@i].Price" class="form-control" name="RowList[@i].Price" value="33" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[@i].Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**2. This is the backend code**

```
 [BindProperty]
    public InvHeader InvHeader { get; set; } = default!;
    public IList<InvRow> RowList { get; set; }


    public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
    {

        var rr = new List<InvRow>()
        {
            new InvRow() { Name = "Apple", Qty = 5, Price = 100 },
             new InvRow() { Name = "Peach", Qty = 3, Price = 500 },
              new InvRow() { Name = "Ananas", Qty = 1, Price = 1100 },
        };

        RowList = rr;

        return Page();
    }



    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IList<InvRow> RowList)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

         _context.InvHeaders.Add(InvHeader);

        await _context.InvRows.AddRangeAsync(RowList);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```