# How to insert multiple rows with AddRange in ASP.NET Core Razor pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am trying to insert some rows on submit, but I get zero rows saved. I know that something is wrong, but I am not able to understand what.

How to make this work?

This is the frontend code:

```
// Here the rows are inserted 
<form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        @{
            int i = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model.RowList)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-4">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[i].Name" class="form-control" value="@item.Name" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[i].Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-4">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[i].Qty" class="form-control" value="@item.Qty" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[i].Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-4">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[i].Price" class="form-control" value="@item.Price" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[i].Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            @(i++)
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the backend code

```
    [BindProperty]
    public InvRow InvRow { get; set; }
    public IList<InvRow> RowList { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
    {
        var rr = new List<InvRow>()
        {
             new InvRow() { Name = "Apple", Qty = 1, Price = 100 },
             new InvRow() { Name = "Peach", Qty = 1, Price = 500 },
             new InvRow() { Name = "Ananas", Qty = 1, Price = 1100 },
        };

        RowList = rr;

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IList<InvRow> rw)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.InvRows.AddRange(rw);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to insert some rows on submit, but I  get zero rows saved.
> I know that something is wrong, but I am not able to understand what.

You are getting expected result because, you have defined your [BindProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bindproperty-attribute) as `RowList` which is wrapping your view items as RowList[], RowList[] and so on as you can see below:

[image]

Therefore, you should extract those property as RowList but in your OnPostAsync method you  have defined as rw which mismatched with your bind property defination and consequently you are getting 0 row.

Solution:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IList<InvRow> RowList)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.InvRows.AddRange(rw);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

**Note:** You even can rename your bindProperty as well which should be matched with your [form name attribute property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/4-working-with-forms) which currently set as RowList.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bindproperty-attribute)