# Why are the values (qty, price, sum) saved as zero on submit, when i successfully copy the values from dropdownlist to input, with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor

**1. Explaination**

I am copying the product (quantity, price) from a dropdownlist to inputs.

Then find the sum of qty * price on the third input.

If the quantity or price changes, the sum is updated and is successfully shown on its input.

The code is the default "Create" page, what i have changed is only the dropdownlist, where i can get qty and price values.

**2. The problem**

On submit, the input values (qty, price, sum) are always saved as zero.

**3. Question**

What is wrong with this code?

**4. The frontend + javascript code**

```
 <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="InvRows.ProdId" class="control-label">Produkti</label>
            @*<select asp-for="InvRows.ProdId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProdId"></select>*@
            <select asp-for="InvRows.ProdId" class="form-control"
                    style="width:100%;font-size:80%;" id="xprod">
                <option value="">--- Product name ---</option>
                @foreach (var item in Model.PL)
                {
                    <option value="@item.ProdId" qty="1"
                            price="@Convert.ToInt32(item.Price)">
                        @item.Prodname
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="InvRows.Qty" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="InvRows.Qty" class="form-control" name="Qty" id="xqty" />
            <span asp-validation-for="InvRows.Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="InvRows.Price" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="InvRows.Price" class="form-control" name="Price" id="xPrice" />
            <span asp-validation-for="InvRows.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="InvRows.Sum" class="control-label">Shuma</label>
            <input asp-for="InvRows.Sum" class="form-control" name="Sum" id="xSum" />
            <span asp-validation-for="InvRows.Sum" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
    
    
    
    @section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
```

// The dropdownlist,  onchange method

```
<script>

$("#xprod").change(function () {

    $("#xPrice").val($("#xprod").find("option:selected").text());
    getSum();
})
function getSum() {
    var sum = parseInt($("#xPrice").val() * $("#xQty").val());
    $("#xSum").val(sum);
};
```

```
// The qty/price, onchange method


<script>

$("#xQty").keyup(function () {
    getSum();
})
    $("#xPrice").keyup(function () {
        getSum();
    })
function getSum() {
    var sum = parseInt($("#xPrice").val() * $("#xQty").val());
    $("#xSum").val(sum);
};
```

//The first function that copies values from dropdownlist to inputs

```
<script>
    //ok

    $("#xprod").change(function () {
        var qty = $(this).children('option:selected').attr("qty");
        var price = $(this).children('option:selected').attr("price");

        document.getElementsByName("Qty")[0].value = parseInt(qty);
        document.getElementsByName("Price")[0].value = parseInt(price);
        document.getElementsByName("Sum")[0].value = parseInt(price);

    });
</script>
```

}

Comment: You use `val` in some functions and `attr` in others

Comment: I am not so good with javascript. The methods used, have been found on the web. I have just adapted them to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I think when user select an option in dropdown list, the value of the option will be filled into `Price` input tag automatically, Then Regardless of user input quantity or select price from dropdown list, The sum(quantity * price) will be filled into sum input tag
automatically, Because you don't provide your model design, I create a simple demo with hard code, Hope it can help you solve this issue.

**Model**

```
public class InvRows
    {
        public int ProdId { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Sum { get; set; }
        public List<Select> PL { get; set; }
    }
public class Select
    {
        public int ProdId { get; set; }
        public string Prodname { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

**Page code**

```
@model InvRows
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ProdId" class="control-label">Produkti</label>
        @*<select asp-for="InvRows.ProdId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProdId"></select>*@
        <select asp-for="ProdId" class="form-control"
                style="width:100%;font-size:80%;" id="xprod">
            <option value="">--- Product name ---</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.PL)
            {
                <option value="@item.ProdId" qty="1"
                        price="@Convert.ToInt32(item.Price)">
                    @item.Prodname
                </option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Qty" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Qty" class="form-control" name="Qty" id="xqty" onchange="QTY()" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" name="Price" id="xPrice" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Sum" class="control-label">Shuma</label>
        <input asp-for="Sum" class="form-control" name="Sum" id="xSum" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Sum" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script>
        $("#xprod").change(function () {

            
            var price = $("#xprod option:selected").attr("price");
            $("#xPrice").val(price);

            getSum();
        });

        function QTY() {
            var sum = parseInt($("#xPrice").val()) * parseInt($("#xqty").val());
            $("#xSum").val(sum);
        }

        
        function getSum() {
            var sum = parseInt($("#xPrice").val()) * parseInt($("#xqty").val());
            $("#xSum").val(sum);
        };
    </script>
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

**When I submit the form, Post method can receive data successfully**

[image]

**BTW:** `asp-for` tag will generate `name=xxx` and `id=xxx` automatically in html, If you are using nested model, You need to use `name="InvRows.Qty"` instead of `name="Qty"` to bind the value in backend. In my opinion, you don't need to manually specify name's value, Just let `asp-for` tag generate it automatically .

Comment: Sorry you are right. Here is all the code (front/backend)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716824/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-with-addrange-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages      The only difference is that, when i save the data as a list, and one row is empty it gives me an error, so by now knowing how to solve this i want to do it by inserting a single row of data, with _context.InvRows.Add(InvRow). Hope it answers your question.

Comment: The answer is just based on this post. I am glad to see you have solved issue. If this answer can give you some help, could you mark it as the answer? thank you so much.