# How to omit the empty rows, with addrange, on ASP.NET Core Razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

> **1. Explaination**

I can successfully insert multiple rows with `Ilist<Rowlist>`, but if i do not fill all the rows with values it gives me an error and does not save any data.

```
    For example, i have declared 10 new rows for input, but i need to use only 5 of them; 
    
    on submit i get an error that some rows are empty.
    

    **The full code of inserting/saving the rows is on:** 
    
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716824/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-with-addrange-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages
    
    **I have already checked the link below, for some help, but still was not able to find a solution.**
    
    
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bindproperty-attribute
```

> **2.Question**

How can i save only the rows that are not empty and omit the rest?

> **3.The Frontend code**

```
 <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @{
                int i = 0;
            }
            @foreach (var item in Model.RowList)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[i].Name" class="form-control" value="@item.Name" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[i].Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[i].Qty" class="form-control" value="@item.Qty" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[i].Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.RowList[i].Price" class="form-control" value="@item.Price" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.RowList[i].Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @(i++)
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

> **4. The Backend code**

```
 [BindProperty]
        public InvRow InvRow { get; set; }
        public IList<InvRow> RowList { get; set; }
```

// The Onget method

```
public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
        {
            var rr = new List<InvRow>()
            {
                 new InvRow() {  },
                 new InvRow() { },
                 new InvRow() {  },
                  new InvRow() {  },
                 new InvRow() { },
                 new InvRow() {  },
            };
    
            RowList = rr;
    
            return Page();
        }
```

// The Onpost method

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IList<InvRow> RowList)
        {
       
    
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
    
            _context.InvRows.AddRange(rw);
    
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so you have a class called **InvRow**. A good first thing you could do is add an **IsEmpty()** method in it, something like:

```cs
public class InvRow
{
    // Your existing properties

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) || Qty == 0 || Price == 0;
    }
}
```

As for your **OnPostAsync()** method, You can first filter out the empty rows using **LinQ** and the **IsEmpty** method you just added, then call AddRange. Something like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IList<InvRow> RowList)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    // Filter out empty rows
    var nonEmptyRows = RowList.Where(row => !row.IsEmpty()).ToList();

    // Add non-empty rows to the database
    _context.InvRows.AddRange(nonEmptyRows);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Comment: I do make use of scaffolding, when i need to make code changes, is there any other way except that declaring the 'IsEmpty()' method inside the class? How should this code be if i populate/select the name from a dropdownlist?

Comment: I dont know why but i get this error: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MYAPP.Models.DB.InvRow]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MYAPP.Models.DB.InvRow]'.      error on :   _context.InvRows.AddRange((IEnumerable<InvRow>)nonEmptyRows);

Comment: You could have the method IsEmpty() in an extension class, so IsEmpty would be an extension method and therefore, not in your class.